# How to retrieve only those contacts which have more than one phone number?

Tags: android

I am retrieving all contacts but I want to retrieve only those contacts which have more than one mobile number.

This is my code snippet

```
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == 1) {
        String[] numbers = null;
        int i = 0;

        String phoneNumber = null;
        String id = null;
        String name = null;

        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = cr.query(data.getData(), null, null, null, null);

        if (cur.getCount() > 0) {

            while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

                if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                    Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{id}, null);
                    numbers = new String[pCur.getCount()];
                    while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                        phoneNumber = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                        numbers[i] = phoneNumber;
                        i++;
                    }
                    pCur.close();
                    etNumber.setText(phoneNumber);
                }
            }

        }
        cur.close();
        AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        ad.setTitle(name);
        ad.setItems(numbers, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        });
        AlertDialog adb = ad.create();
        adb.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: plan B: just fetch all of them and filter out the ones you don't want

Comment: can you share the code or you can modify in my shared snippet code  , I am not getting what you wanna say. Thanks in Advance